# TeeChartVCLFMX-2018.24 and Builder 10.2.2

Tags: delphi, teechart

I tried to install "TeeChart VCL/FMX v2018 Pro Evaluation version - Online" on a  Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.29039.2004.

Installation works fine but when I launch Delphi Embarcadero, I have errors :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're experiencing is caused because you aren't using the **Rad Studio 10.2 Tokyo update 3 version 25.0.29899.2631** and latest TeeChart Pro VCL/FMX v2018.24 is only supported for that.

You can download Rad Studio 10.2 Tokyo Update 3 from the link below:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44774

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run both the installer and the IDE with high privileges ("Run as Administrator").

Since you already installed TeeChart, you can just run "TeeInstall.exe" in the installation folder with high privileges to reinstall the components into the IDE, without having to fully reinstall the components.

Comment: I tried (uninstall with TeeInstall.exe and install with high privileges and run Delphi 10.2 with high privileges), but still have the same error messages...

Comment: When I go on Component -> Install Packages on Delphi 10.2. I can add DclTee925.bpl (TeeChart Standard 2018 Components) but If I remove this one and I try to add DclTeePro925.bpl, I have errors (like on photos)...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshots, it seems the bpls are in 2 locations (System32 and the Teechart output folder).

As I have encountered this issue too in the past, I would suggest the obvious by manually deleting the relevant teechart .bpl files from your windows system folders. 
Take care to remove them from *both* the 32bit and 64bit system folders

```
- C:\Windows\System32\*925.bpl
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\*925.bpl
```

as well as from the BDS folders:

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Redist\win32
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Redist\win64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Redist\<others platforms you may use>
```

When deleting them ensure no delphi or one of your own apps is running as this prevents the bpls from being deleted. After doing so, teerecompile shouldn't complain anymore. So this is a "one shot" fix. After this you should be able to rely on TeeRecompile.

**BTW**: by removing I mean move them to a different folder rather than deleting them, so you can restore. didnt think of it as I use a VM for development and can always easily roll back.

**OOPS**: I overlooked the fact you cannot recompile. Nevertheless, I think the bpl removal tip still is valid.